# XMLHttpRequest error in firefox whereas working in chrome (xhr.status===0) in firefox and xhr.status ===200 in chrome

Tags: javascript, json, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm developing a firefox extension and repeadtly getting **xhr.status===0**  error in firefox extension I'm using **firefox 31 and addon sdk 1.17** , whereas when I tried same on chrome it worked . I 'm sending a **GET** request to a website to retrive it's **json file** and I have added permissions tag in my package.json file

```
enter code here
xhr.open("GET", "http://www.hackerearth.com/chrome-extension/events/", true);
  xhr.send();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if(xhr.readyState===4){
        if(xhr.status===200){
          console.log(xhr.responseText);
          var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
          console.log(err+"the eerrrorr");        

      }else{
        alert("Status is :"+xhr.status);
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: If you can edit to make it a little more clear what you're asking, without rambling, this could possibly be reopened. Please see [ask] for more guidance. Good luck!

Comment: @jmort253 okk I take care of this practice

Comment: The question seems a bit better asked, but you still need to provide the code that's causing the problem (or ideally the smallest bit of code that you can come up with that shows your problem).

Comment: That's weird man i just pasted your code and it worked fine for me. Can copy paste this to scratchpad it works fine: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/0fae8c5b4d2930fdc48a see this image of me running it in scratchpad: http://i.imgur.com/oNlg3be.png  i put arrow on "Environment" menu cuz if u want to do same make sure to set environemnt to "Browser"

Comment: Was your issue resolved man? Your code worked fine for me.

Comment: Yes @Noitidart this is resolved

Comment: Thanks man for letting me know. Can you please share how you resolved it. Like a pastebin and then link in comment and once this gets reopend we can post it as solution here.

Comment: Actually I was appending the js file in html page, in case of a request it is not allowed to have a xmlhttprequest inside an html file but when It is called from contentScriptFile tag from  main.js it responded . The ***xhr.status*** is used for getting the response of the server side so in case of this the info cannot be made .

Comment: @user1305313 please post your comment again as solution of this topic.